# Owl Carousel having problem when window resizing

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

I have an owl carousel of images and then when I resize or just press f12, it will show little photos. My initialization is based on the button the user is clicking. For example, I have 5 buttons, If i press one button, other carousel should destroy  and the div will be hidden. but then, when I press and press f12 and press a button again, it will show me little thumbnails. Please see photo for reference.

[image]

After pressing f12

[image]

here is my code in script.js

```
$("#residential").click(function(){

            destroy_owl($('#gallery-slider-office'));

            destroy_owl($('#gallery-slider-educfacilities'));

            destroy_owl($('#gallery-slider-clubhouse'));

            destroy_owl($('#gallery-slider-workshop'));

            destroy_owl($('#gallery-slider-commercial'));
            initialize_owl($('#gallery-slider-residential'),'.residential-nav');
            $( "#residentialdiv" ).fadeIn('slow');
            $("#residentialdiv").show();
            $("#officediv").hide();
            $("#mainphotos").hide();
            $("#educfacilitiesdiv").hide();
            $("#clubhousediv").hide();
            $("#workshopdiv").hide();
            $("#commercialdiv").hide();
        });

function initialize_owl(el,nav) {
        el.owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            smartSpeed: 500,
            autoplay: 4000,
            items:1,
            dots:true,
            navText: [
                '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
                '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
            ],
            navContainer: nav,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:2
                },
                800:{
                    items:3
                },
                1024:{
                    items:4
                },
                1200:{
                    items:4
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function destroy_owl(el) {
        el.owlCarousel('destroy')
    }
```

my html

```
   <div class="main-content residential" id="residentialdiv">
                            <div class="gallery-slider-residential residential owl-carousel owl-theme" id="gallery-slider-residential">
                                <div class="gallery-item">
                                    <div class="gallery_box">
                                        <div class="gallry_wrp">
                                            <img src="images/gallery/residential/1.jpg" alt="">
                                            <div class="gallery_info">
                                                <h4 class="heading"><a class="lightbox-image" data-fancybox-group="residential-gallery-1"  href="images/gallery/residential/1-whole.jpg">View Photo</a></h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <ul class="link_icons">
                                                <li><a class="lightbox-image" data-fancybox-group="residential-gallery-2" href="images/gallery/residential/1-whole.jpg"><i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                   </div>
 <div class="owl-theme">
                            <div class="owl-controls">
                                <div class="custom-nav owl-nav residential-nav"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you can share website link where you have faced this issue so I can help you to fix this issue.

Comment: @TanmayPatel blp-sg.com

Comment: Have you tried it with latest version? Your version seems to be old 2.0!